# strict negativity of upper right Dini derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, delay-differential-equations

I'm trying to prove the global asymptotic stability of an equilibrium of a system of delay differential equations. After adopting the Lyapunov functional approach, I arrive at the upper right Dini derivative along the solution curves:
$$
D^{+}V(t)\leq\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\xi_k\left\{-|y_k(t)+x_k^{\ast}|+
\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}c_j|a_{kj}||y_j(t)|
+h_k\left(
\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}|a_{kj}|\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}|y_j(t-u)+x_j^{\ast}|f_{kj}(u)du\right)\right\},
$$
where $h_k:\mathbb{R}\mapsto [-1,1]$ is a hyperbolic tangent function,
$x_k^{\ast}$, $k=1,\ldots,n$, are real constants, $f_{kj}:\mathbb{R}\mapsto (0,1]$, $k,j=1,\ldots,n$ is a sequence of delay kernels, $c_j,\xi_j$, $j=1,\ldots, n$, are positive real parameters, $a_{kj}\in\mathbb{R}$, and the unknown $y_k$, $k=1,\ldots,n$, satisfies the system of delay differential equations
$$
y_k^{\prime}(t)= -\left(y_k(t)+x_k^{\ast}\right)+h_k\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}a_{kj}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\left(y_j(t-u)+x_j^{\ast}\right)f_{kj}(u)du\right)\;,\;\;k=1,\ldots,n,
$$
An important condition arising from the theory of M-matrices is that
$$
-\xi_j+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}c_k|a_{kj}|\xi_k<0\;,\;\;j=1,\ldots,n.
$$
In view of all of the above information, I wish to establish that, under certain conditions, $D^{+}V(t)<0$. I have heard and read that Razumikhin-type arguments are an option, but I'm not exactly sure how such arguments may be applied to the present problem.

Comment: What is the reason for keeping the $c_k$ and $a_{kj}$ as separate parameters? Why not write the equation for the vector $y$ as $y'(t) = -y(t) + \int_0^\infty C(u)y(u) du$ where $C_{kj}(u) = c_ka_{kj}f_{kj}(u)$?

Comment: The vector $y$ satisfies a linear integrodifferential equation whose asymptotic behavior can be completely understood by taking the Laplace transform.

Comment: I've revised the problem so that the system of delay differential equations satisfied by $y_j$ is nonlinear. This is the general setting of the problem.